# PHP and Multiple MySQL Connections

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, scalability

I have a webapp written in PHP that currently creates a DB connection (using mysqli_connect) on every page to pull data from the database.

Recently, my website has slowed down (with some traffic increase), and I was wondering if the creation of so many connections - one for every user that is on any page - is causing the slow down?

Is there any fix for this?

Is it possible to create one sharable connection for the server? I know this is possible in python, but I do not know how I would implement such a model in PHP.

Note: My site is on BlueHost...I don't know if that also makes a difference.

Comment: why do think that the DB connections are slowing down your site?

Comment: That does not slow down your server at all for any "not so terribly huge" traffic. Did you look at queries how much time they are taking?

Comment: I know in Python the connecting to the DB has high overhead, and recently my site has slowed down - sometimes the server takes 20s to load. Queries take max .5s.

Comment: If your queries are ok, it most probably is a load-balancing issue. That's why the server is taking long to respond.

Comment: @Nicky93 I thought "your coding style is always hit when execute query". That's not a good habit. You should avoid to hit database everytime. This one is one of the fact of performance issue.

Comment: @Thiha - I'm confused as what you mean?

Comment: @om_deshpande - Load balancing issue? My side or Bluehost?

Comment: Bluehost. On shared hostings, a site can slow down if there is a spike in traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Well two things to do.

1. Setup the slow query log in MySQL and see if there are queries that
   are slow. Optimize these slow queries by using the `EXPLAIN` command
   to identify missing indexes etc.
2. Setup connection pooling to eliminate opening a connection all the
   time. See this link [Connection Pooling In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264415/efficient-way-to-connect-to-a-database-when-multiple-functions-are-running-queri/18264467#18264467) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend host by "p:" when passing it to `mysqli_connect` to open a persistent connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Persistent Connections from the links below:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

But I would strongly suggest **NOT** to use Persistent Connections.

You will need to find out what is actually slowing your website.

Ping a website that loads fast for you. eg. google.com.
Ping your webserver, if the ping difference is a lot then you should ask BlueHost to resolve it.

Check whether there is any lag between your Web Server and Database Server. They could probably be:

- on the same machine (mostly no lag)
- on different machines in the same local network (mostly no lag unless there is a LAN problem, ask BlueHost)
- on different machines in different networks (there could be issues, ask BlueHost if they could shift the Database Server within the same Local Network)

If everything above is fine and the pages are still loading slowly.

You could try explicitly calling mysqli_close() after your DB work in the page is done. This will free up your connection immeditely instead of waiting for the page to fully execute. You will then need to figure what is slowing the page after your DB work is over.

You can use mictotime() on your slow pages to see what code is slowing it down.
You could use this link: [Accurate way to measure execution times of php scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245971/accurate-way-to-measure-execution-times-of-php-scripts)